# Pactester dont find Pacfile

Tags: networking, vmware

If I run

```
pactester -p wpad.dat -u http://google.com
```

on terminal, as it says in the manual i get this error

```
pacparser.c: pacparser_parse_pac: Could not read the pacfile: : wpad.dat: No such file or director
pactester.c: Could not parse the pac file: wpad.dat
```

Do I need to enter the exact URL? If yes how can i get it? 
I have Ubuntu 12.04 running on a VmWare Player

Hope someone can help me

Greetings

Comment: Are you sure `wpad.dat` is located in your working directory?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pactester is a tool to test proxy auto-configuration (PAC) files. So you need to create a `wpad.dat` file to configure the sites you want to have direct connection with and the sites you want to access using the proxy server. For example, the following `wpad.dat` file will bypass proxy for all hosts that are in the same subnet or in `10.0.0.0` but will access all other sites using the proxy server:

```
function FindProxyForURL(url, host)
{
  if (isInNet(myIpAddress(),"192.168.2.0","255.255.255.0")) return "DIRECT";
  if (isPlainHostName(host) ||
      isInNet(host, "10.0.0.0", "255.0.0.0")
    return "DIRECT";
  else
    return "PROXY proxy_host:port_no";
};
```

As you can see the `wpad.dat` file is a javascript file.

So, the problem is you don't have a `wpad.dat` file which will tell pactester what rules to follow for various hosts. You need to create that first.

[(Source)](https://kb.bluecoat.com/index?page=content&id=KB3264&actp=LIST_POPULAR)

Comment: Ah OK I understand, is there a way to get the pac file from a certain proxy server?

Comment: @user273566: I am not aware of a method to do that.